# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null what should do?

Tags: laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = new product1();
    $file = $request->file;

    $filename= time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file->move('assets', $filename);
    $data->file = $filename;
    $data->name = $request->name;

    $data->description = $request->description;
    $data->author = $request->author;
    $data->comment = $request->comment;

    $data->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

View:

```
<form action="{{ url('uploadproduct') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Write comment" type="text" style="  width: 50%;">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Done" style="  width: 20%;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your input file in this form?

Comment: Just change this to `$file = $request->file('file');`

Comment: <form action="{{ url('uploadproduct') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Write comment" type="text" style="  width: 50%;">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Done" style="  width: 20%;">
    </div>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

`$file` is null when trying to get its properties.

You can either condition the process to the existence of `$file` (in case that the 'file' input is not required), or simply check what is happening that input value is null when requesting it.

Maybe there's no `<input type="file" name="file">` in your form...

Or maybe your form has no `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property that allows you to submit files.

I DO also recommend you to validate your request before processing the data: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    // Here you start processing your inputs
}
```

Comment: <form action="{{url('uploadproduct')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group">
  
      <input class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Write comment" type="text" style="  width: 50%;">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Done" style="  width: 20%;">

    </div>
</form>

Comment: Where's the file input? Please, check carefully what you're doing. You're checking a file that is not even being submitted.

Comment: its comment form so user can write a comment and click done to submitted to the data base

Comment: Then, check what you're doing in your controller. You can't ask for a non-existent input.